# How to add Action Bar in relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-relativelayout

Actually i want to put Action Bar menu into my layout given below, i am no getting how to put the Action  bar menu into it. Can anyone help me in fixing this problem...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:id="@id/action_bar"
>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enable Pin"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enable Pattern"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

first you must use tool bar because action bar is deprecated 
and for that add below code to your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/back">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        />
 <!-- add your other layout component here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

and in your activity you must extend form appcompactActivity like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
}
```

and in the style.xml add this code: specially this `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: hey @ali what i want is that, to show the actionbar in to my page after the main screen with the title "Enable Pin"... for that what should i do??

Comment: hey  @Sam  try to adding getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title"); after setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Answer (score 0):

You should use Toolbar, since ActionBar is deprecated. Add this in your layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary” />
```

Depending on your other project files, you may need to modify the styles.xml and your activity. Check out [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) for more info.